# I got "Access is denied" when try to run .bat and .exe with different user on Windows servers

Tags: windows, batch-file, permissions, access-denied, windows-server-2016

So, I have one Windows server 2016 VM which I currently having this issue where users including me unable to run .bat and .exe file as different user account (Shift + Right click and run as different user) although the same user account able to RDP to the server and double click on that bat file as well as able to run it through CMD and when I check the effective access it does show that every account that got the access is denied message have the full permission

[Access is denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o0RF.png)

Any idea...?

Checking effective access and even adding everyone to have full permission.

I'm expecting that I and end users will be able to run the bat file as different user.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is the solution. I found the [Error when you use the runas command, the Run as Administrator option, or the Run as a different user option after you upgrade Windows Server: Access is denied](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/shell-experience/access-denied-runas-command-run-as-administrator) is for Windows server 2012 R2 but it does fix the issue for Windows server 2016 as well.

Run the below command as admin.

```
sc sdset seclogon D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWRPDTLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWDTLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;CCLCSWRPDTLOCRRC;;;AU)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
```